# Difference between "Importing into module" and "Importing into resource" in terraforn

Tags: terraform

I was reading Terraform's docs and I found these two commands:

- [Import into resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/import.html#example-import-into-resource)

```sh
$ terraform import aws_instance.foo i-abcd1234
```

- [Import into module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/import.html#example-import-into-module)

```sh
$ terraform import module.foo.aws_instance.bar i-abcd1234
```

So I was wondering what's the practical difference within terraform's state when you execute these two commands.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by "practical difference"? These are still same instances, just one is in the module and the other is not. There are represented same in the state file as both are `aws_instance` resources.

Comment: I'm quite new to terraform so I didn't understand what's the difference between using these two commands.
What will happen if by mistake I use one instead of the other?

Comment: If you don't have module defined in your TF code with the `aws_instance` and name `bar`, then importing to module would fail. Same for the other case. To import, you have to first manually prepare matching TF configuration of the resource that you want to import.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When running `terrafom import` Terraform expects the [resources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/index.html) you're importing to to be defined in your configuration.

For your first case `$ terraform import aws_instance.foo i-abcd1234` you would need to define at least:

```
# main.tf
resource "aws_instance" "foo" {
}
```

Terraform will update the statefile with details from AWS.

In the second one `$ terraform import module.foo.aws_instance.bar i-abcd1234` Terraform expects module 'foo' containing resource 'aws_instance bar' to exist. Check on [when to create modules](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/index.html) and [how to compose them](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/composition.html). E.g.

```
# modules/foo
resource "aws_instance" "bar" {
}

# main.tf
module "consul_cluster" {
  source = "./modules/aws-consul-cluster"
}
```

If you will check the statefile you'll see that your imported resource is nested differently.

Comment: I think `foo` in this line `resource "aws_instance" "foo"` is supposed to be `bar`

Answer (score 0):

If you import something into a resource that you later want to convert into a module, you need to re-import (and remove your original import from state). Worth bearing in mind as your codebase evolves.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).